# MongoDb sharding and string ids

Tags: java, mongodb, sharding, morphia

We are working on an application which we need to use String ids as mongodb id.My question is : If we make sharding on mongodb, will string ids cause any problem?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the string?

Answer (score 1):

That heavily depends on the content of the string. Surnames, for example generally make a bad shard key for *automatic* balancing, as there is an uneven distribution of the letters surnames start with in almost every language. This problem, however, can be overcome with [tag based sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/administer-shard-tags/#manage-shard-tags), though this requires quite a bit of knowledge and configuration when scaling.

Hashing of the string was already mentioned, but I would like to add that you can run into problems with geographically distributed datacenters when doing so, since you wouldn't be able to assign the correct id ranges to their geographical location any more in case this is what your ID is (partially) made of.

Another solution might be to use a compound shard key.

Answer (score 0):

No, they can/should/will be hashed before being sharded. (might imply a slight cost in computer power though).

Comment: They will only hashed if you create a hashed index

Comment: @Sammaye Yes of course. I have corrected my answer to be more specific to this regard.